# Facebook on PhoneGap/Cordova -- File protocol?

Tags: javascript, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, parse-platform

Have searched everywhere for this without luck.  I'm getting this error when running PhoneGap app on device (works fine in browser):

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

This is because I haven't added the host to the facebook app configuration.  BUT, PhoneGap/Cordova accesses the app through the file:/// protocol, so there's no domain for me to add to Facebook.

Potential options: 1) Figure out how to use a cordova native plugin (this is hard because we're using Parse), 2) Switch Cordova to use localhost instead of file:// (not sure how to do this).

Answer (score 1):

I've been down this road and ultimately went with option #1. Since we're not really dealing with a website there is no domain to add. Cordova needs to use file:// I don't think there is any way around it. The trick with using the plugin is keeping the login status in sync with Parse (use Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn). He's some code that should help you out. This is how I check the login status:

```
try {
      console.log("Trying to get FB login status");
      return FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        var accessToken, currentView, expDate, facebookAuthData, uid, user;
        console.log(response);
        if (response.status === "connected") {
          uid = response.authResponse.userID;
          accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
          console.log("Logged in!");
          user = Parse.User.current();
          if (user != null) {
            console.log("we have a user");
          } else {
            console.log("we don't have a user... need to login with parse");
            expDate = new Date(response.authResponse.expirationTime);
            facebookAuthData = {
              id: response.authResponse.userID + "",
              access_token: response.authResponse.accessToken,
              expiration_date: expDate.toISOString()
            };
            Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(facebookAuthData, {
              success: function(_user) {
                return console.log("Logged in with Parse!");
              },
              error: function(error1, error2) {
                return console.log("Unable to create/login as Facebook user");
              }
            });
          }
        } else {
          // not logged in to fb... 
        }
      });
} catch (e) {
    return console.log(e);
}
```

Here's how I handle logins:

```
return FB.Event.subscribe("auth.authResponseChange", function(response) {
      var expDate, facebookAuthData;
      if (response.status === "connected") {
        console.log(response.status);
        try {
          expDate = new Date(response.authResponse.expirationTime);
          facebookAuthData = {
            id: response.authResponse.userID + "",
            access_token: response.authResponse.accessToken,
            expiration_date: expDate.toISOString()
          };
          return Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(facebookAuthData, {
            success: function(_user) {
              //return window.location.hash = "loginsuccess";
            },
            error: function(error1, error2) {
              console.log("Unable to create/login to as Facebook user");
            }
          });
        } catch (ex) {
          return console.log("parse login error " + ex);
        }
      } else if (response.status === "not_authorized") {
        // handle not auth event
      } else {
        // take them home?
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @bmurmistro, question: what version of cordova plugin and facebook are you using?  Wondering if most of our woes are just being on the wrong versions of things

Comment: seems like the FB.* methods are deprecated and have to use facebookConnectPlugin.*, but not seeing anywhere confirming that

Comment: @pfrank sorry for the delayed response and for any confusion. This is the plugin that I'm using: https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect
Let me know if you have any questions or issues.